# Swift - Segue to wrong index when UISearchBar is active

Tags: ios, swift, search, tableview

I am new to code, and I just can't find the solution to this problem. Most of the answers on the internet are deprecated or unanswered.

I want to search something into my searchbar, after that I want to press on one of the results. When I click on the result I want it to give me the corresponding information in another viewcontroller.

**Here's my problem:** When I click on a result, the information in the other viewcontroller doesn't correspond with the information that the result gave me. What he does gives me is the information that corresponds to the tableview. So, it segues with a wrong index. Does anyone knows what the solution is?

**Here's my code (tableviewcontroller with searchbar):**

```
   var myIndex = 0
   extension UIColor { //themakleur
   static let candyGreen = UIColor(red: 71.0/255.0, green: 81.0/255.0, blue: 
   89.0/255.0, alpha: 1.0)}

   var watjeberekend = ["Omtrek Cirkel","Oppervlakte Cirkel","Lengte 
   Boog","Oppervlakte Sector","Oppervlakte Bol"]

class scheikunde: UITableViewController, UISearchResultsUpdating {

var scheikundeformules = ["Omtrek Cirkel","Oppervlakte Cirkel","Lengte Boog","Oppervlakte Sector","Oppervlakte Bol"]
var searchcontroller : UISearchController!
var filterednamen = [String]()


override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    self.searchcontroller = UISearchController(searchResultsController: nil)
    self.tableView.tableHeaderView = self.searchcontroller.searchBar
    self.searchcontroller.searchResultsUpdater = self
    self.searchcontroller.dimsBackgroundDuringPresentation = false
    definesPresentationContext = true
    self.navigationItem.hidesBackButton = false;
    self.navigationController?.isNavigationBarHidden = false

    //navigationcontroller layout
    navigationController?.navigationBar.barTintColor = UIColor(red: 71.0/255.0, green: 81.0/255.0, blue: 89.0/255.0, alpha: 1.0)
    navigationController?.navigationBar.titleTextAttributes = [NSForegroundColorAttributeName: UIColor.white]
    navigationController?.navigationBar.layer.borderColor = UIColor.candyGreen.cgColor
    navigationController?.navigationBar.layer.borderWidth = 0

    //searchcontroller layout
    searchcontroller.searchBar.layer.borderWidth = 0
    searchcontroller.searchBar.layer.borderColor = UIColor.candyGreen.cgColor
    UISearchBar.appearance().barTintColor = .candyGreen
    UITextField.appearance(whenContainedInInstancesOf: [UISearchBar.self]).tintColor = .candyGreen
    searchcontroller.searchBar.backgroundImage = UIImage(named: "themakleur.jpg")
    let cancelButtonAttributes: [String: AnyObject] = [NSForegroundColorAttributeName: UIColor.white]

    UIBarButtonItem.appearance(whenContainedInInstancesOf: [UISearchBar.self]).setTitleTextAttributes(cancelButtonAttributes, for: .normal)

}

func updateSearchResults(for searchController: UISearchController) {
    self.filterednamen = self.scheikundeformules.filter { (naam : String) -> Bool in
        if naam.lowercased().contains(self.searchcontroller.searchBar.text!.lowercased()) {
            return true
        }else{
            return false}}
        self.tableView.reloadData()
    }


override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    if !searchcontroller.isActive || searchcontroller.searchBar.text == "" {
        return self.scheikundeformules.count
    }else {
        return self.filterednamen.count
        }
    }


override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) as! Custommath

    cell.label.text = scheikundeformules[indexPath.row]

    if !searchcontroller.isActive || searchcontroller.searchBar.text == "" {
        //cell.textLabel?.text = self.namen[indexPath.row]
        cell.label.text = self.scheikundeformules[indexPath.row]
    }else{
        //cell.textLabel?.text = self.filterednamen[indexPath.row]
        cell.label.text = self.filterednamen[indexPath.row]
        }
        return cell
    }



override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    myIndex = indexPath.row
    performSegue(withIdentifier: "segue", sender: self)

    }
}
```

**Here is my code from the viewcontroller:**

```
        import UIKit


        class scheikundeformule: UIViewController{

@IBOutlet var uitleg6: UILabel!
@IBOutlet var formuleomschrijving: UILabel!
@IBOutlet var uitleg5: UILabel!
@IBOutlet var uitleg4: UILabel!
@IBOutlet var uitleg3: UILabel!
@IBOutlet var uitleg2: UILabel!
@IBOutlet var uitleg1: UILabel!
@IBOutlet var titlelabel: UILabel!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    titlelabel.text = scheikundeformules[myIndex]
    uitleg1.text = uitlegformules2[myIndex]
    uitleg2.text = uitlegformules3[myIndex]
    uitleg3.text = uitlegformules4[myIndex]
    uitleg4.text = uitlegformules5[myIndex]
    uitleg5.text = uitlegformules6[myIndex]
    uitleg6.text = uitlegformules7[myIndex]

    self.navigationItem.hidesBackButton = false;
    self.navigationController?.isNavigationBarHidden = false
    formuleomschrijving.text = watjeberekend[myIndex]

    //keyboard weg deel 1
    let tap: UITapGestureRecognizer = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(startscreen.dismissKeyboard))

    //Uncomment the line below if you want the tap not not interfere and cancel other interactions.
    //tap.cancelsTouchesInView = false
    view.addGestureRecognizer(tap)

}
override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()

 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Where is your function prepare for segue ? if you want to pass the data to the next view controller  you need to send it in the fun prepare for segue, and remember that the indexpath.row needs to be used with the array that is the current datasource of the tableview, the solution will be something like this:

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
 if let destinationVC = segue.destination as? YourViewController {
     if !searchcontroller.isActive {
         destinationVC.name = filterednamen[myIndex]
     } else {
            destinationVC.name = scheikundeformules[myIndex]
       }  }
}
```

Comment: Thx for the comment! What do you mean with destination.name? @LuizPerez

Comment: DestinationVC is your next view controller, the one that will be showing after you select one row of the tableview, that viewcontroller needs a variable that can hold the value that you are passing, so destinationVC.name is the reference to that variable.

Comment: he gives an error when I type destinationVC.name. "Value of type "scheikundeformules" has no member "name" @LuisPerez

Comment: The code above is an example of how you work with tableviews and filters, your tableviewcontroller has 2 arrays, one that is filtered and one that isn’t, i don’t recommend passing the indexpath because as I posted above, the indexpath works for the array that the table is using as data source, so if you just pass the indexpath to the next viewcontroller the arrays of information might not be the same, and it will show the information incorrectly, my sugestión, add a variable named “name” in your destination viewcontroller, and then fill the labels with that data.

Comment: last question, which data? I don't quite understand... @luisperez

Comment: ok, you say that your main issue is that you want to pass data (a String or anything) from your tableviewcontroller to another viewController, you need to pass the data stored in the array scheikundeformules located in the indexpath.row selected by the user, but if the user is searching, you need to pass the data from filterednamen instead of scheikundeformules, so why instead of passing the indexpath.row, why don't you pass the data (String in this case ) ? that way you don't get incorrect data from your arrays, you access directly to the information stored.

Answer (score 0):

Add identifier for `scheikundeformule` view controller in storyboard like below :

**Step 1:**

[image: Step 1:]

**Step 2:**
change your tableview didSelectRow like below :

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    myIndex = indexPath.row

    let scheikundeformuleController = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "scheikundeformule") as! scheikundeformule
    scheikundeformuleController.myIndex = indexPath.row
    self.present(scheikundeformuleController, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

**Step 3:**

You have to add `var myIndex = 0` to your `scheikundeformule` controller. Like below :

```
class scheikundeformule: UIViewController{
    var myIndex = 0
    ........Your code
}
```